# Vectorization / speed up for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a pandas DataFrame "data" and want to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"col": [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.1,5,0,0,0],
                    "t": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})

for i in range(1,len(data)):
        if(data["col"][i]==0):
            data["t"][i] = data["t"][i-1]+1
        else:
            data["t"][i] = 0
```

It work's like it should be, but unfortunately it's really slow. Is there a possibility to speed this code up? For example with vectorization?

**Expected output**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.1,5,0,0,0],
                     "t": [0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3]})

    col  t
0   0.0  0
1   0.0  1
2   0.0  2
3   1.0  0
4   0.0  1
5   0.0  2
6   0.0  3
7   0.1  0
8   5.0  0
9   0.0  1
10  0.0  2
11  0.0  3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you need a simple [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) statement

```
np.where(df.col.eq(0), df.t.shift() + 1, 0)
```

---

Edit:

Really hard to understand what OP wants with lack of example, but IIUC, the following should work:

```
ans2 = df.groupby((df.col.eq(0).shift() != df.col.eq(0)).cumsum()).t.cumcount() + 1

df['ans2'] = np.where(df.col.eq(0), ans2, 0)
```

Comment: Well.. Im shooting in the dark here, but gave another try. @Python_Trader take a look

Comment: As far as I can see the "Edit" it's what I want. Thank you!!! Will need some time to fully understand the code :D btw. it's really fast. From some minutes to two seconds.